# htmllize paragraph that each line begins with x spaces

Tags: regex

I get:

```
TRUC BIDULE
       one line.

MACHIN
       first line with characters.
       second.

NAWAK
       first line with characters.
       second.

       one line.
```

And I need:

```
TRUC BIDULE
<p>one line.</p>

MACHIN
<p>first line with characters.
second.</p>

NAWAK
<p>first line with characters.
second.</p>

<p>one line.</p>
```

regex is super powerful, but it is pulling out hair.
For over an hour I try and I'm sure some of you could do it in 2 minutes.
On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bN8fM1/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise to transform the input string in 2 runs.
Run 1: Getting rid of space spans and replacing them with `<p>...</p>`.

> *Regex:* `" {7}([\S ]+)+\n"`

See [your updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/bN8fM1/5).

Run 2: Replace the `<p>`s referring to 1 paragraph.

> *Regex:* `"</p>([\r\n]{1})<p>"`

See the [<p> removing regex here](https://regex101.com/r/bN8fM1/8).

Comment: I need only one paragraph for x line consecutive begin with 7 spaces. Your example does not works. Thanks

Comment: @Mauricio: I see, the example output should have signaled I was wrong. I updated the answer with a 2 regex run suggestion. It is much easier than to play with capturing groups.

Comment: If I understand correctly this is not possible in a single pass.
I am far from being familiar with regex but I thought that was possible in a single pass. 
I hear almost every day grace to your people like you.
I will probably follow your advice.
Thank you yet again for header uses interested my problem.

Comment: If the number of lines inside 1 paragraph is a set number (e.g. always 2 lines), then it is possible to do it in one go (pattern: " {7}(.+)(?:[\r\n]+ {7}((.+)))?\n", replacement = "<p>\1\n\2</p>\n"), but you might not like the newline before `</p>` (I do not see any problem with that since it is OK for HTML). Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/zE3wT4/1.

Comment: Unfortunately the number of line is variable.
It's really very nice to be able to rely on strangers. Do not bother more with my problem. I will follow your advice and do it it in 2 steps.